# Ajax method displays the wrong input

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am posting again a question about which I didn't have a satisfactory answer :

I am new to AJAX methods. I want to post some infos that are processes by a php page, call it page.php

In my html page, I have put this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//I have put the function getXMLHttpRequest() on a separate js file
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xhr = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        } else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
        return null;
    }

    return xhr;
}

function request(callback) {
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "page.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("name=proposition");
}

function postData(Data) {

    alert(Data);

}
</script>

<button onclick="request(postData);">...</button>
```

In page.php, I have a method

```
function comment(){
  //some code processing the posted infos (that works fine)...
  //to debug, I have put a
  echo('Hello world');
}
```

More precisely : the structure of page.php is `page.php?page='mypage'&post='post'`.So first there is a direction to a mypage.php, and then in mypage.php there is an instanciation of a class. The `__construct` method takes the post variable to call a method within the class which is `comment()`.

The fact is I don't get any 'Hello world' but a huge alert message with all my webpage code displayed.
Anyone has an idea ?

Best, Newben

Comment: If you don't get any satisfying answers, try to improve your original question, don't just post the same question again.

Comment: I suggest you take a few steps back. Unless you're wanting to learn to build your own ajax library, don't use the xhr object directly. Use a library like jQuery. There are many, many situations that come up with ajax that you aren't aware of, and your code doesn't deal with them. jQuery already handles all of those situations. Use jQuery.

Comment: may I ask you why you did not use jQuery and did not replace this whole code with just a single line: 
`$.post("page.php", function(data){ alert(data); });` ?

Comment: ... or [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) ;-)

Comment: by the way, I do not get how you handle this part with `"page=mypage"` with javascript code? and, if you are using variables in url, why are you using POST request instead of GET?

Comment: For sure, but it's rather philosophically speaking that I want to really know what is going on when the xhr object is used !

Comment: I want to use ajax methods to 'post' some comments in on a forum I am building

Comment: and a tip for debugging: change $_POST to $_REQUEST [ so you can handle post and get at the same time ] and try to open www for which the AJAX request is being made. If you see the whole web site, it means that your php code is wrong, not javascript

Comment: It didn't change anything. Perhaps the problem i that there is a redirection : the page.php redirects to mypage.php and then displays all mypage.php. By the way, I am sure of my php code

Answer (score 2):

I agree with mkk and also strongly recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for Ajax-stuff - it will safe you *a lot* of headache and safely handle the error-prone processes for you. It takes only one line in your head-section to import it:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ...
<head>
<body>

<script>
  $('#my-btn').click(function() {

    var data = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'};

    $.post('page.php', data, function(callback_data){
      alert(callback_data);
    });

  });
</script>

<button id="my-btn">Make an Ajax request!</button>

<body>
```

And in page.php:

```
<?php
  echo 'The following data was sent: <br />';
  print_r($_POST);
```

Usually you want to fetch some data from DB and then write it to your frontend. In this case it's common to work with JSON. 
Actually you should just have a look at some useful jQuery functions, like [post()](http://docs.jquery.com/Post) and [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), they have a lot of good examples which will quite give you an idea of the capabilities. If you don't like jQuery, it's fine, you won't even notice it's there while working with 'normal' JavaScript. But when it comes to Ajax-Requests, you really should use jQuery.  And talking about JSON, you will probably also need [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the server side.

Actually it's quite hard to guide you in general, please get a little more familiar with the techniques and come back if you encounter some problems that are hard to ask at google.

Comment: Thank you for this complete response, but it's quite frustating not to understand how all this works, without using jquery :)

Comment: It works pretty much the same without jQuery - jQuery is completely based on JavaScript, it just encapsulates some frequently used functions like an Ajax-Request and handles the whole setup for you, so you just need to call one function. But you can still use JavaScript inside or outside of the function. Again: It just does the same what you did in your code, just in an approved and safe way, and then encapsulates everything in one function. So instead of messing around with ActiveXObjects and stuff you just need to call `$.post(target,data,callbackfunction);`

Comment: @Newben And if you *really* want to see how it actually works, just have a look at the jQuery sourcecode (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js, search for e.g. 'ActiveXObject') and you'll see, that you don't really want to do this on yor own... ;-)